# UIButton is outside of ContainerView

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift, and I'm trying to learn how to build iOS apps programmatically, with very limited use of the Storyboard. Right now, the goal is to create a menu at the top of the app, which will contain buttons. Based off of my research, it appears that the best way to do this is to nest the UIButtons inside of a ContainerView. However, the issue is that my UIButton is displayed outside of my ContainerView. Perhaps I need to set constraints on the ViewContainer and my UIButton?

Could you guys please point me in the right direction? Your help is very much appreciated.

Storyboard:

[image]

App Simulator (iPhone 7 Plus):

[image]

HomeController.swift:

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {
    let topMenuContainerView = UIView()
    topMenuContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(topMenuContainerView)

    let topMenuController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Top_Menu_View_Controller")
    addChildViewController(topMenuController)
    topMenuController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    topMenuContainerView.addSubview(topMenuController.view)
    topMenuController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

TopMenuController.swift:

```
class TopMenuController: UIViewController {
    let createAdButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.roundedRect)

    createAdButton.setTitle("Create Ad", for: UIControlState.normal)
    createAdButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    createAdButton.frame = view.frame
    createAdButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    view.addSubview(createAdButton)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe adding constraints will solve your problem. It would be something like this:

```
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: createAdButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: createAdButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
```

BUT, wouldn't it be better to have just a UIView inside your Home Controller instead of a View Controller just for the menu?

Comment: I'd be a bit stronger with the concern about View Controller's here.  A `UIViewController` is intended to present an entire screen full of information.  There are some uses of `UIViewController` that allow them to take over part of the screen, but this is usually done in the context of a structuring view controller like a split view controller, or a popover controller.  I would consider long and hard before deciding to set up a custom scheme that used multiple view controllers on the screen at once.